# Is removing an audio segment on YouTube a lossless operation?

Tags: encoding, youtube

YouTube marked part of a video I uploaded as containing copyrighted audio. When I remove that audio segment on the YouTube website, does YouTube re-encode the audio of my whole video? Or is the removal or substitution of audio on YouTube a lossless operation?

It seems it is lossy, as it takes quite a while for it process the audio removal. There's really no reason it should be lossy.